# Resolving unmet dependancy in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, apt

I am geeting the folowing error when i tried installing beanstalkd `(sudo apt-get install beanstalkd)` and I even tried -f option but none helped what can id do

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  beanstalkd: Depends: libevent-1.4-2 (>= 1.4.13-stable) but it is not going to be installed
  mysql-server-5.1: Depends: mysql-client-5.1 (>= 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libmysqlclient16 (>= 5.1.21-1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.1 (>= 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?  Have you run `apt-get update`?  Are you using any third-party repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resolve dependencies manually.

try to install listed dependencies, using

```
aptitude install libevent-1.4-2
aptitude install mysql-common
aptitude install mysql-client-5.1
aptitude install libmysqlclient16
aptitude install mysql-server-core-5.1
```

Installation of some of this will  may fail - you probably will need to install it manually using `dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/packagename.deb`